# Where are the default search/query options stored in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

I know I can read these using the /v1/config/query/(default|{name}) (GET) REST API (and set them too), but I'd like to know where they are stored either in the file system or the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can also retrieve them with [`search:get-default-options()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/search:get-default-options)

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
    at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";
search:get-default-options()
```

And if you look at the implementation of that method, you will find that the `get-default-options()` in */Modules/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy* returns the variable `$impl:default-options` which is defined in */Modules/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search-impl.xqy*.

There you will find the default search options.

Comment: Interesting - I wish there was a search:set-default-options() function to run in the QC. Otherwise I can wrap a REST call in an http call in the QC to enable and disable search options. At a minimum it is easier than try to enable and disable options for debugging and analyzing query plans in complex and custom node.js and xquery code.

Comment: yeah, it would be convenient to be able to alter the defaults and not have to explicitly send options in every request. Though you could create your own library that wraps search and applies your custom options as the default.

Comment: So are the search options cached? I don't think that updating them actually updates the config in search-impl.xqy. If cached, when do they revert back to their original values?